# Click to show hidden text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to figuring out how to hide and display text through JavaScript. There is a script that I am loading here `<script src="js/mail-generator.js"></script>` to generate the message data.

Here I am grabbing the sender from the `mail-generator.js` with this code bellow.

```
        var sender = currentMessage.sender;
        var body = currentMessage.body;
        var date = currentMessage.date;
        var subject = currentMessage.subject;

        // Sender 
        var mySenderElement = document.createElement('div');
        mySenderElement.setAttribute('id','sender')
        mySenderElement.innerHTML = sender;
        mainElement.appendChild(mySenderElement);
```

This gives me this result in the HTML `<div id="sender">Rick Roger</div>`

Now I want fetch the message data and I do this here

```
        // Body 
        var myBodyElement = document.createElement('div');
        myBodyElement.setAttribute('id','body');
        myBodyElement.innerHTML = body;
        mainElement.appendChild(myBodyElement);
```

My result is this in the HTML

```
<div id="body">We need to save Buffy from Hansel and Gretel. Well, you were busy trying to get yourself lit on fire. The only thing Willow was ever good for, the only thing I ever had going for me were those moments, just moments, where Tara would look at me and I was wonderful. Everyone's a hero in their own way, in their own not that heroic way. Planet's coming up a mite fast.</div>
```

What I want to happen is for `body` to be hidden when the page loads. In the place of `body` I would like to have a little bit of text saying *click to read message* and when clicked upon the `body` message appears.

**Here is a link to my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kapena/6qf4j8cn/**

I have a feeling that the solution has something to do with a `.addEventListener("click", myFunction);` Just not sure on how to hide the paragraph and place in text saying click to read the message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Just starting JS so please bare in mind that I am a beginner. Even just point me in the right direction would be cool :)

Thank you

Comment: Your feeling is good, continue into that direction.

Comment: Is it possible to instead to utilize document.write(message); instead of hide/unhide it?

Comment: What is then the purpose of jQuery tag???

Comment: If you don't want a jQuery answer, why have you tagged it as a jQuery question?

Comment: @BrentWhite That's not the purpose of TAGs

Comment: @Bartdude can you point me to a reference you may know of or some type of fiddle with an example?

Comment: I could point you to google but you don't need me for that. As an indication, hiding/showing something is actually manipulating the CSS property `display` , so you might just search on how to manipulate css with POJS

Comment: @Bartdude thax man! I've was searchin around google for a few mins before i hit this post up. Wanted to post a SO and see the results I got here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're learning, I'm going to do a lot of explaining, so please don't TL;DR. :-)

Two different approaches:

#### A separate element

There are three/four parts to what you want to do:

1. Having `myBodyElement` start out hidden.
2. Having something else on the page that says "Click to read message".
3. Having that something else respond to the click...
4. ...by by hiding/removing itself (presumably) and showing `myBodyElement`.

Step 1 is done by setting the `display` property of the element to `none`. Just after your line setting the `id` attribute:

```
myBodyElement.style.display = "none";
```

Step 2 is done by appending another element to the page much the same way you do the `myBodyElement` element. You already have the code for that.

Step 3 is done exactly as you indicated, by using `addEventListener` on the element we added in Step 2:

```
clickToRead.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Code to handle the click here
}, false);
```

Step 4 is done by using that `.style.display` property again, this time setting the `myBodyElement.style.display` to `"block"` (the way `div`s are usually displayed) and setting the `.style.display` element of `clickToRead` to `"none"`:

```
clickToRead.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Hide clickToRead
    clickToRead.style.display = "none";
    // Show myBodyElement
    myBodyElement.style.display = "block";
}, false);
```

Alternately, you could *remove* the `clickToRead` element:

```
clickToRead.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Remove clickToRead
    clickToRead.parentNode.removeChild(clickToRead);
    clickToRead = null;
    // Show myBodyElement
    myBodyElement.style.display = "block";
}, false);
```

#### Swapping text

An entirely different approach would involve using `myBodyElement` itself and just swapping out its `innerHTML`. This is actually much simpler.

Instead of your

```
myBodyElement.innerHTML = body;
```

line, use your message instead:

```
myBodyElement.innerHTML = "Click to read message";
```

Then add the handler as we did earlier, but to `myBodyElement`:

```
myBodyElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Handle click here
}, false);
```

Then you probabaly already know what to do: Set `innerHTML` again within the handler:

```
myBodyElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    myBodyElement.innerHTML = body;
}, false);
```

Now, one more piece of that puzzle: We're still responding to clicks and re-setting `innerHTML`. That's probably not ideal, we should probably stop responding to clicks. This adds (a little) complication: We need to remember the function we used as a handler so we can remove it later:

```
var handler = function() {
    myBodyElement.innerHTML = body;
    myBodyElement.removeEventListener("click", handler, false);
};
myBodyElement.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
```

Comment: This is a very didactic approach and I respect that, so I upvoted. Also with your  current reputation you probably know SO way better than me, but don't you think answering it encourages questions like this while from where I see it this is not exactly what is wanted on SO ? The fact the OP is learning and shows he actually did some other code made me not downvote or close the question, but still I personnally don't want to encourage it by giving a whole tutorial solving this particular problem.

Comment: @T.J. Thank you for your feedback I really appreciate you taking the time to write out the steps and go over this with me clearly and precisely! I have learned from your answer. Bartdude I also understand your point. However I came here to find a more direct answer for what I was seeking to do. Is this not encouraged on SO? As I said I am just a beginner here. We all haft to start out somewhere..

Comment: @Bartdude what type of questions are encouraged to be asked on SO? No beginner questions?

Comment: @BrentWhite > usually questions with some coding attempts to do what you want to do. This to limit the number of "please do that for me" questions which are legion here though. However, I agree sometimes you just don't know where to start or what to look for, and you clearly looked like being in that position. In that case, I generally prefer giving hints (like I did) than doing it as I think trying, making mistakes, do some research and try again is how you learn and even discover stuff not related to your question that could be of use later.

Comment: @Bartdude: My view is that this question is entirely appropriate for SO: The OP needed some help, had clearly made an effort to find what they were looking for, but still hadn't put it quite together. Not at all a "no effort" question. It's a fine line and honest people can draw that line in different places, fair enough; for me, this question was fine (ugh, couldn't come up with a different word).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have been struggling with finding my way past step 2. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kapena/6qf4j8cn/23/ As you can see I have appended the new element to the page through calling the variable of `readmsg` which stores a string containing the msg.

Comment: @BrentWhite: See http://jsfiddle.net/6qf4j8cn/24/ - There were two main problems there. 1. You were being hit by jsFiddle's *very surprising default* which is to wrap everything in the JavaScript panel in a `window.onload = function() { ... };` function (it's the second drop-down on the top left, you want "No wrap" not "Onload"). 2. You didn't define the `mailme` global. There are other problems: You have a loop, but your elements have `id`s. `id`s must be **unique** on the page. (I don't see that any of the elements you're creating needs an `id` at all.) HTH,

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thats what I thought it was. I ended up changing the `id` s to class and got the `addEventListener` working. However just to point out I got a **stuck** with step two. Can you make that step just a little clearer? I needed to append another element to the page but I was not sure how exactly this should be handled as you said I already have the code for this. Can you please explain.

Answer (score 2):

I am aware you are after a pure Javascript solution, but for those interested - this can (almost) be entirely achieved in purely HTML/CSS:

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
input + span {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + span {
  display: block;
}
input:checked + span + span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span>this is your message!</span>
  <span>click to read message</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

First add `display:none;` to your `<div id="body">`. This hides the element when the page is loaded.

Then add a button that will change the div's display to `block` and change its own display to `none` when clicked.

```
<button id="b" onclick="document.getElementById('body').style.display='block';document.getElementById('b').style.display='none';">Click to show message</button>
```

And you should be good. [Your JSFiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/6qf4j8cn/5/).